# Customizing Streamplot with other plots

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying plot vector field of a dynamical system together with highlighting some area using some inequality constraints.

My state-variable for vector fields are $x$ and $y$.

The following are the parameters used for the vector field

```
ls = 2*10^-3; 
cs =  2*10^-3; 
g = 0.03; 
p1 = 1000; 
pi1 = 1100; 
is = 0; 
ki = 0; kd = 1; yd = 380;
```

The vector fields are given by f1 and f2:

```
f1 = -(pi1/y^2 + kd)* cs^-1*(x - g*y - p1/y - is) - (ki + ls^-1)*(y - yd);
f2 = cs^-1*(x - g*y - p1/y - is);
```

I have used the following code to Draw the vector SteamDensity plot

```
StreamDensityPlot[
 {f1, f2}, {x, xd - 100, xd + 100}, {y, yd - 100, yd + 100},
 StreamPoints -> {{{{xd, yd}, Blue}, {{xd - 50, yd - 50}, 
     Green}, {{xd + 50, yd + 50}, Red}, Automatic}},
 PlotRange -> {{xd - 100, xd + 100}, {yd - 100, yd + 100}},
 FrameTicks -> {{-50, {14, 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(I\), \(*\)]\)=14 A", {.5, 0}, 
     Thickness[0.001]}, 50}, {250, 300, 
    350, {380, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(V\), \(*\)]\)=380 V", {.5, 0}, 
     Thickness[0.001]}, 450}},
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 FrameLabel -> {Current  , Voltage },
 PlotLegends -> Automatic,
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome",
 StreamPoints -> Fine,
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Orange, 50]
 ]
```

This resulted in the following plot:

[image: Stream plot]

However, I am want to highlight the area inside the plot satisfying $370<y<410$. I checked all the option of `StreamDensityPlot` but didn't find any relevant function that does this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting a [`Rectangle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle.html) in [`Epilog`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Epilog.html):

```
StreamDensityPlot[{f1, f2}, {x, xd - 100, xd + 100}, {y, yd - 100, 
  yd + 100}, 
 StreamPoints -> {{{{xd, yd}, Blue}, {{xd - 50, yd - 50}, 
     Green}, {{xd + 50, yd + 50}, Red}, Automatic}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{xd - 100, xd + 100}, {yd - 100, yd + 100}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{-50, {14, 
     "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(I\), \(*\)]\)=14 A", {.5, 0}, 
     Thickness[0.001]}, 50}, {250, 300, 
    350, {380, "\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(V\), \(*\)]\)=380 V", {.5, 0}, 
     Thickness[0.001]}, 450}}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 FrameLabel -> {Current, Voltage}, PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
 PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", StreamPoints -> Fine, 
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Orange, 50],
 Epilog -> {Orange, Opacity[0.5], 
   Rectangle[{xd - 100, 370}, {xd + 100, 410}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]